# Azure Video Indexer Download Url

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

Hello we need to generate an azure videoindexer download url that is being used by some downstream systems. The current rest api response generates the url with an expiry date.  We need a longer expiry or for a url that does not expire. Any idea what parameter or a way to get thus link.

I generate from this Rest Api call
https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=Get-Video-Artifact-Download-Url
I do not see an option for expiry

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. This is something we can consider. Please add this ask to the user voice https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

> We need a longer expiry or for a url that does not expire. Any idea
> what parameter or a way to get thus link.

Based on the documentation provided, I don't think it is possible to have a URL with an expiry date more than 1 hour.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-for-media-docs/video-indexer-use-apis#obtain-access-token-using-the-authorization-api):

> Access tokens expire after 1 hour. Make sure your access token is
> valid before using the Operations API. If it expires, call the
> Authorization API again to get a new access token.